# Algebra solution problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations

How many possible solutions are there to this problem?
$$ 10 \leq n_{1} + n_{2}+ n_{3}+ n_{4}+n_{5} \leq 20, $$
where $$ n_{k}\geq2$$ I've tried listing out the possible solutions for each number between 10 and 20. For example, with 13 you can have some permutation of 5 and four 2s. So that would be 5 solutions. You could also have some permutation of 4, 3, and three 2s. So that would be 5!/3!. And you can have some permutation of three 3's and two 2's. That would be 5!/3!2! solutions. The issue is when you start getting to higher numbers it becomes extremely difficult to keep listing out possible solutions. Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to solving this problem or maybe there is some faster way to list out the solutions. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Consider starting where each $n_k = 2$ and "placing" $10$ identical ones into the five $n_k.$

Comment: simplify the problem by substituting $m_k +2= n_k$ first

Answer (score 1):

I assume you require the numbers to be integers.

Clearly, this is equivalent to asking: how many solutions are there to

$m_1 + m_2 + m_3 + m_4 + m_5 \leq 10$

where the $m_i$ are nonnegative integers (aka natural numbers)? For each solution $(m_1, ..., m_5)$ to the above inequality, I have the solution $(m_1 + 2, ..., m_5 + 2)$ to your inequality. And for every solution $(n_1, ..., n_5)$ to your inequality, I have the soluition $(n_1 - 2, ..., n_5 - 2)$ to my inequality.

Now, we note that this is equivalent to counting the number of natural number solutions to

$m_1 + m_2 + m_3 + m_4 + m_5 + m_6 = 10$

Since given such a solution, it's clear that we can take $(m_1, ..., m_5)$ as a solution to the inequality, and given a solution to the inequality, we can take $(m_1, ..., m_5, 1 - (m_1 + ... + m_5))$ as a solution to the equation.

To solve this, we use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). The solution is $\binom{15}{5} = 3003$.